# GraphQL Expected Iterable but did not find field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, graphql, apollo

I am trying to implement GraphQL but always get the error of Expected iterable. As I understand there can be an error with the types, but i tried everything and don't know what to do

that's what my API returns

```
        {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "bitcoin",
          "rank": "1",
          "symbol": "BTC",
          "name": "Bitcoin",
          "supply": "17193925.0000000000000000",
          "maxSupply": "21000000.0000000000000000",
          "marketCapUsd": "119150835874.4699281625807300",
          "volumeUsd24Hr": "2927959461.1750323310959460",
          "priceUsd": "6929.8217756835584756",
          "changePercent24Hr": "-0.8101417214350335",
          "vwap24Hr": "7175.0663247679233209"
        },
     ......
]
}
```

and here is my code

```
  const coinType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Coin',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLString },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
  })
});

// Root Query
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootQueryType',
  fields: () => ({

    coin: {
      type: new GraphQLList(launchType),
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return axios
          .get('https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets')
          .then(res => res.data);
      }
    },
  })
});

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: RootQuery
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is because mismatch between the return type of the resolver and your schema. Check for returning Object instead of Array or something in that sense. You may post the schema just in case.